# What happens with a HTTP response to a garbage-collected HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, http, oauth-2.0, garbage-collection, es6-promise

**Background**

I have an app that authenticates with a cloud service via the OAuth 2.0 protocol. I use a third party library to make the HTTP request and wrap the call to this library in a `Promise`. I also make sure that this call can timeout. The code basically looks like this:

```
var authenticate = new Promise (resolve, reject) {

      service.authenticate(callback); // The third party library HTTP request

      if (responseData === 'authenticated') {
          resolve();

      } else {
          reject();
      }
}

var timeout = new Promise (resolve, reject) {

    setTimout (function() {reject();}, 2000}
    }

Promise.race([authenticate, timeout])
    .then(resolved)
    .catch(rejected);
```

The app immediately makes a new authentication attempt if the preceding one is rejected. That means that a new `Promise` is immediately assigned to `var authenticate`. That means that the preceding `Promise` assigned to `authenticate` gets garbage collected (I guess - please correct me if I am wrong).

**Question**

What happens if the cloud service responds with an access token in relation to the garbage collected `Promise`?

Answer (score 0):

The promise isn't garbage collected.

Note that `resolve` and `reject` need to be passed into the function doing the asynchronous authentication somehow, otherwise there's no way they can be called later, so lets assume it says:

```
service.authenticate(resolve, reject);
```

This is important, because in order to complete the authentication, the function obviously needs hold on to the functions `resolve` and `reject`, which in turn keep the returned promise alive, regardless of whether `authenticate` still references it.

So what'll happen is that the promise will resolve (or reject if there was an error) just as one would hope.

The fact that your code has given up on it doesn't change this.

If it rejects then most browsers will show an error in web console about this *unhandled rejected promise*, since this is considered a programming error.

Comment: Thank you for your response. *First:* `service.authenticate` is just a simplified way of representing a call made to at third party library. So there is no resolve or reject which needs to be passed into it. *Second:* “The promise isn’t garbage-collected”. `foo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){}`, `typeof foo === ‘object'); // true`. As you can see a Promise is an object which is referenced by the variable foo.

Comment: So if the reference is removed, the Promise object fulfills both the reference-counting and mark-and-sweep algorithms for being garbage-collected. I have a hard time understanding why these algorithm should not apply to a Promise object. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: The functions `resolve` and `reject` still reference the promise. It wouldn't be garbage collection if you could trip over it like this in JavaScript.

Comment: But the reference to the `resolve` and `reject` functions are passed as arguments to the `Promise` constructor and therefore it is the `Promise` instance referencing `revolve` and `reject` and not the other way around .... or ?

Comment: That's backwards. The code (in the function you pass to the promise constructor) that ultimately calls `resolve` and `reject`, is holding references to `resolve` and `reject` - or it couldn't call them - which in turn hold references to the promise they resolve/reject. You're not passing in `resolve` and `reject`, those are arguments passed to you.

Comment: Also, it doesn't help that your code example is wrong: it synchronously resolves or rejects the promise right away. You should updated it to actually be asynchronous.